# Animated text within box

Tags: html, css

I have the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/florinpop/uexwLy75/).

With the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="animated-box">Animated box</div>
```

CSS:

```
.animated-box {
    border:2px solid #bada55;
    border-radius: 10px 0;

    color: #bada55;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;

    padding:50px;
    width:200px;

    -webkit-animation:fontbulger 1s infinite;
    -moz-animation:   fontbulger 5s infinite;
    -o-animation:     fontbulger 1s infinite;
    animation:        fontbulger 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fontbulger {
  0%, 100% {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  50% {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fontbulger {
  0%, 100% {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  50% {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes fontbulger {
  0%, 100% {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  50% {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
@keyframes fontbulger {
  0%, 100% {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  50% {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

How can I change the size of the text, but not the size of the box?

Comment: give it a fixed height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a `line-height`, for example

```
line-height:20px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uexwLy75/2/

Comment: What is by default the `line-height` value? Auto?

Comment: @FlorinPop default is `line-height:normal`. What this translates is browser specific & dependant on the chosen font family, [for example Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) is "roughly 1.2"

Answer (score 1):

Give it a `height: 30px;`

```css
.animated-box {
    border:2px solid #bada55;
    border-radius: 10px 0;
    
    color: #bada55;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    
    padding:50px;
    width:200px;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-animation:fontbulger 1s infinite;
    -moz-animation:   fontbulger 5s infinite;
    -o-animation:     fontbulger 1s infinite;
    animation:        fontbulger 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fontbulger {
  0%, 100% {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  50% {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fontbulger {
  0%, 100% {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  50% {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes fontbulger {
  0%, 100% {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  50% {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
@keyframes fontbulger {
  0%, 100% {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  50% {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animated-box">Animated box</div>
```